# Customize array structure

Tags: php

How to Convert following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_num] => 1400236903
            [status] => unpaid
            [payment_rec_date] => 2014-05-16
            [description] => 
            [actual_amount] => 200 
            [stax] => 20.00
            [stax_value] =>30.00 
            [ed_tax] => 31.21
            [ed_tax_value] => 30.00
            [w_ed_tax] => 25.00
            [w_ed_tax_value] => 55.56 
            [amount] => 12000
            [total_discount] => 152
        )
   [0] => Array
        ( .....
         )
)

into 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_num] => 1400236903
            [status] => unpaid
            [payment_rec_date] => 2014-05-16
            [description] => 
            [actual_amount] => 200 
        [data] => {"stax":20.00, "stax_value":30.00,"ed_tax":31.21,"ed_tax_value":30.00,"w_ed_tax":25.00..... }
        )
)
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please explain what are you trying to achieve. You want the array in a particular type, tell us how it is different from the other one. Have you checked the array functions supported by php array_keys, array_search etc. ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. To get the solution for your question follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://eval.in/612031

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> You could simply do that using `foreach` within `array_walk()`. That could give you the result you want. 
> **Part 1:** The Algorithm — without the Sample array. ( [Quick Test it Here.](https://eval.in/612037))

```
    <?php

    $arrResult  = array(); //$arr IS THE MAIN ARRAY TO CLEAN UP
    $arrFin     = array_walk($arr, function($data, $index) use (&$arrResult){
        $clone      = $data;
        $sifts      = array('stax', 'stax_value', 'ed_tax', 'ed_tax_value', 'w_ed_tax', 'w_ed_tax_value', 'amount', 'total_discount');
        $tempObj    = new stdClass();
        foreach($clone as $k=>$v){
            if(in_array($k, $sifts)){
                unset( $clone[$k] );
                $tempObj->$k = $v;
            }
        }
        $clone['data']  = $tempObj;
        $arrResult[]    = $clone;
    });

    var_dump($arrResult);
```

> **Part 2:** The Algorithm — with Sample array.([Quick Test it Here.](https://eval.in/612037))

```
<?php

    $arr        = array(
        array(
            'order_num'         =>1400236903,
            'status'            => 'unpaid',
            'payment_rec_date'  => '2014-05-16',
            'description'       => null,
            'actual_amount'     => 200,
            'stax'              => 20.00,
            'stax_value'        => 30.00,
            'ed_tax'            => 31.21,
            'ed_tax_value'      => 30.00,
            'w_ed_tax'          => 25.00,
            'w_ed_tax_value'    => 55.56,
            'amount'            => 12000,
            'total_discount'    => 152,
        ),

        array(
            'order_num'         =>3098786903,
            'status'            => 'paid',
            'payment_rec_date'  => '2014-05-16',
            'description'       => "Lorem Ipsum",
            'actual_amount'     => 200,
            'stax'              => 20.00,
            'stax_value'        => 30.00,
            'ed_tax'            => 31.21,
            'ed_tax_value'      => 30.00,
            'w_ed_tax'          => 25.00,
            'w_ed_tax_value'    => 55.56,
            'amount'            => 12000,
            'total_discount'    => 152,
        ),
    );

    $arrResult  = array();
    $arrFin     = array_walk($arr, function($data, $index) use (&$arrResult){
        $clone      = $data;
        $sifts      = array('stax', 'stax_value', 'ed_tax', 'ed_tax_value', 'w_ed_tax', 'w_ed_tax_value', 'amount', 'total_discount');
        $tempObj    = new stdClass();
        foreach($clone as $k=>$v){
            if(in_array($k, $sifts)){
                unset( $clone[$k] );
                $tempObj->$k = $v;
            }
        }
        $clone['data']  = $tempObj;
        $arrResult[]    = $clone;
    });

var_dump($arrResult);
```

> The **var_dump($arrResult)** above produces the Following output below: ([Quick Test it Here.](https://eval.in/612037))

```
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'order_num' => int 1400236903
          'status' => string 'unpaid' (length=6)
          'payment_rec_date' => string '2014-05-16' (length=10)
          'description' => null
          'actual_amount' => int 200
          'data' => 
            object(stdClass)[2]
              public 'stax' => float 20
              public 'stax_value' => float 30
              public 'ed_tax' => float 31.21
              public 'ed_tax_value' => float 30
              public 'w_ed_tax' => float 25
              public 'w_ed_tax_value' => float 55.56
              public 'amount' => int 12000
              public 'total_discount' => int 152
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'order_num' => int 3098786903
          'status' => string 'paid' (length=4)
          'payment_rec_date' => string '2014-05-16' (length=10)
          'description' => string 'Lorem Ipsum' (length=11)
          'actual_amount' => int 200
          'data' => 
            object(stdClass)[3]
              public 'stax' => float 20
              public 'stax_value' => float 30
              public 'ed_tax' => float 31.21
              public 'ed_tax_value' => float 30
              public 'w_ed_tax' => float 25
              public 'w_ed_tax_value' => float 55.56
              public 'amount' => int 12000
              public 'total_discount' => int 152
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and check the keys you want to use.
I use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode your data.

**Solution** :

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'order_num' => 1400236903,
    'status' => 'unpaid',
    'payment_rec_date' => '2014-05-16',
    'description' => '',
    'actual_amount' => 200 ,
    'stax' => 20.00,
    'stax_value' =>30.00 ,
    'ed_tax' => 31.21,
    'ed_tax_value' => 30.00,
    'w_ed_tax' => 25.00,
    'w_ed_tax_value' => 55.56 ,
    'amount' => 12000,
    'total_discount' => 152
);


$newArray = array();
$data = new stdClass();

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    switch ($key){
        case 'order_num':
        case 'status':
        case 'payment_rec_date':
        case 'description':
        case 'description':
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
            break;
        default:
            $data->$key = $value;
    }
}
$newArray['data'] = json_encode($data);

print_r($newArray);
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/mnYoE)